# The Dihedral Group D_12 is a Non-Abelian Group

Tags: group-theory

The question comes from page 29 of Evan Chan's Napkin (https://usamo.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/napkin-2018-08-22.pdf).

[image]

I'm having a hard time understanding his trivia. From what I see, D_12 appears to be commutative but maybe I'm missing something.

[image]

P.S. SOLVED: I was reading compositions the wrong direction and misunderstanding the type of reflections shown in his diagrams. Thank you all for the help and for reminding me why I love this site!

Comment: @JohnNash isn't that for D_10 though? Did I draw the rotations on D_{12} correctly?

Comment: @JohnNash  OP is asking about $D_{12}$

Comment: 360/6=60 so it rotates 60 degree. Now Write all elements then check commutative property.

Comment: Take R₆₀ and H . Now you can see They do not commute. Where H is horizontal reflection

Comment: @JohnNash The original author's reflections were not relative to the horizontal but relative to the vertices themselves. Did he mess up?

Comment: Ohh yes. Did you get it.It is not abelian. And also note that Dₙ is non abelian group of order 2n for every n≥3.

Comment: @JohnNash I checked every element doing his version of reflection and it was abelian. However, I only had to check a couple elements of the horizontal reflection to see that was not abelian. I'm curious why he would explicitly define his method of reflection that way if it doesn't behave the way he intended. I also just realized that I was mistakenly reading the compositions from left to right instead of right to left.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the dihedral group with 6 elements, i.e., the group of isometries of an equilateral triangle is non-abelian and is a subgroup of the group of isometries of a regular hexagon (the dihedral group with 12 elements). (Different authors have different conventions about the notation for the isometry groups of regular $n$-gons a.k.a. [dihedral groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group): some write $D_n$ where $n$ is the number of elements in the group and some write $D_n$ where $n$ is the number of vertices in the $n$-gon.) Rotations and reflections do not commute in general in any dihedral group.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;r\;$ be rotation in $\;60^\circ\;$ (counterclockwise, say) and $\;s\;$ refletion through the diagonal $\;1-4\;$ (the vertical one in your first diagram), then in your upper diagrams, after you apply $\;s\;$ (the application of $\;s\;$ is correct), you actually get $\;5-6-1-2-3-4\;$ , beginning at the top and counterclockwise, not what you wrote there, and the second diagram is correct...so not commutative.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly when the reflection $\;s\;$ is applied, I should always do it through the vertical, not relative to where 1 and 4 are after rotation, right? If that's the case, why didn't he do that in his diagram of D_10?

Comment: @ConnorJames You can choose *any* diagonal of the $\;n\,-$ gon going through the center. I chose the vertical diagonal because it seems to me the easiest to "see", but you can choose any other diagonal. In $\;D_{10}\;$ , the "diagonal" is in fact a segment from a vertex to the middle point of the opposite side...

Comment: thank you. My problem is I read the compositions backwards and though he was moving his reflection axis to stay with his first vertex. Now I see it doesn't matter where you reflect, you just have to be consistent.

Comment: @ConnorJames Exactly: you chose one diagonal to reflect through it, stay with it all the time. Rotations are usually easier to deal with.